# How to get data from a DefaultListModel which have an Object arrayList to put in a Jlist

Tags: java, sql

So, I have an **arrayList** which **contains an Object**. This arrayList **have data which come frome to MySql**. So all of **those data are an Object** which name : alimJcombo() . **I put** all of **those data in a DefaultListModel**.

But after that, **I tried to put them in a Jlist**, without success. How can I do ? can someone help me please ?

Here is the arrayList which contains the Object :

```
public ArrayList<User> alimJcombo()
    {
        Connexion con = new Connexion();
        ArrayList<User> liste = new ArrayList<User>();
        ResultSet res = con.executeRequete("select * from user");
        try {
            while(res.next()) {
                User u = new User(res.getInt(1), res.getString(2), res.getString(3));
                liste.add(u);
            }
            return liste;
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());return null;}

    }
```

Here is the DefaultListModel :

```
DefaultListModel dataList = new DefaultListModel();
dataList.addElement(alimJcombo());
```

Here is the JList :

```
JList list = new JList(dataList.toArray());
scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
```

As you can see in the picture, I managed to display the data. But they are displayed in an array. But that's not what I'm looking for. I want to display them as a list.

my window when I running the previous codes

[image]

Comment: So is your only problem that all of the data inside the "read" text area is on one line and you'd want it to be one line per user?

Comment: Is not my only problem because i also whan to refresh the DefaultListModel in the same JFrame, every time i add a user.
But you are right, I want  my data inside the "read" to be one line per user.